# Antique handling of consequentia mirabilis?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Would Aristotle deem the following [classically valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentia_mirabilis) [[DE](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentia_mirabilis), [DE-to-EN](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FConsequentia_mirabilis)] conclusion

$$\lnot A \rightarrow A \vdash A$$

a *petitio principii*? How would he go about showing it?

Comment: Are you asking how to prove $\lnot A \to A \vdash A$, or asking the historical question of how Aristotle, who did not have modern notation for propositional logic, would have thought about it?

Comment: Good question, @CarlMummert. Thanks for the comment: I just woke up a little while ago! :-)

Comment: Any reason you linked to a German language article? True, the contents of the [English equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentia_mirabilis) is quite unhelpful, but not more so than the German one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought the principle of the consequentia mirabilis was this:

> If the supposition that $\varphi$ is false in fact implies that $\varphi$ is true, then we can conclude that $\varphi$ is indeed true.

If you want symbols, then it is the rule

> $$(A)\quad\frac{\Gamma, \not{\!A}\vdash A}{\Gamma \vdash A}$$

where $\not{\!A}$ indicates the contradictory of $A$, and $\Gamma$ are your background assumptions.

First, contra @amWhy, this is *not* begging the question or circular reasoning: it belongs to the same family of perfectly respectable reasoning as (indeed, is simply the dual of) the reductio proof rule

> $$(B)\quad\frac{\Gamma, A \vdash \not{\!A}}{\Gamma \vdash \not{\!A}}$$

Second, contra @CarlMummert this is nothing specifically to do with the propositional calculus. You could have the rule as a rule of a syllogistic logic which lacks propositional connectives but knows when a pair of wffs are contradictory (so fit the schema with $A$ and $\not{\!A}$).

I'm not sure whether Aristotle himself  ever uses either rule. In his derivation of the validity of Baroco in the *Prior Analytics* he comes close to the first, for he uses this rule

> $$\frac{\Gamma, A, B \vdash \not{\!B}}{\Gamma, B \vdash \not{\!A}}$$

But that's not quite the same. Still, the rules $(A)$ and $(B)$ would seem to be *available* to Aristotle.

Comment: Yes, the natural deduction formulation does the same. Any particular reason to use /A instead of ~A? Is this historical more adequate?

Comment: Traditional syllogistic lacks a negation sign, but does have rules for telling us when a pair of propositions are contradictories (e.g. *All A are B* and *Some A are not B*).

Comment: @CookieMonster Not so. The second rule is NOT implied by cut and the deduction theorem which say nothing about contradictories.

Comment: Why did you write $\not A$ instead of $\lnot A$?

Comment: @PeterSmith sorry, my fault. Was thinking in terms of minimal logic where one additionally assumes /A = A -> f.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is an instance of refutation already observed
by Aristotele. I read:

> Hence if the admitted proposition is contrary
> to the conclusion, refutation must result, since
> refutation is a syllogism which proves the
> contradictory conclusion.
> ([Prior Analytics, II. xx, Tredennick 1949, p.499](https://archive.org/details/L325AristotleIPriorAnalytics/page/499/mode/1up))

Take:

f = contradictory conclusion
/A = admitted proposition
A = conclusion

Than in modern cast with /A = A -> f:

```
                -------- (Id)
G, /A |- A      /A |- /A
------------------------ (Modus Ponens)
       G, /A |- f
       ---------- (Reductio Ad Absurdum)
         G |- A
```

But I am not sure, since I am not an extensive Aristoteles
reader, and since I stepped over this passage by chance.

But if the derivation is done as above, then the consequentia
mirabilis is effectively deduced via double negation elimination,
not doing justice to it.

Bye